# in unix/vim, substitute certain text if the line contains certain text

Tags: unix, vim

For example, given text:

```
source: today is monday  
target: tomorrow is monday
```

I want to substitute `'monday'` with `'tuesday'` if the line contains `'target'`.

Comment: This Q **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://vi.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Use global, `:g` and a normal substitution, `:s`.

```
:g/target/s/monday/tuesday/g
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h :g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) in the pattern to set the start of the match before the desired string:

```
:%s/target.*\zsmonday/tuesday/
```

Another (slightly less readable) possibility is to use the [`\@<=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) look-behind assertion:

```
:%s/\(target.*\)\@<=monday/tuesday/
```